# Video overlay of several network inputs using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-capture, libavcodec, libav

I am writing my first program using the `FFMPEG` libraries, unfortunately it's not a simple one.

What I need is to:

- capture several network inputs(udp).
- demux the inputs.
- overlay the video streams.
- mix the audio(or some other logic).
- encode the resulting streams.
- remux the streams and write the result to file.

For now I am playing with the `ffmpeg.exe` tool trying achieve this functionality. The command I have looks like this:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -threads auto -y -i input0 -i input1 \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080[v0];[1:v]scale=480x270[v1];[v0][v1]overlay=1440:810[v2]" \
    -map [v2] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy output.mp4
```

When `input0` and `input1` are files the resulting output is correct, on the other hand, when the inputs are udp streams the resulting output is not correct, the video freezes most of the time.

The file inputs are generated from the udp streams, using the following command:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -threads auto -y -i "udp://@ip:port" -c copy -f mpegts input1.mpg
```

`Question 1`.
Why is the above command not producing good ouput for udp streams? What are the differences between the original stream and the dump of that stream for `ffmpeg.exe`.

`Question 2`.
Is there some argument/s that can fix the command?

`Question 3`.
What kind of logic/algorithm is needed to correctly overlay two network streams.

Comment: Do you have to use ffmpeg or can other software your meets the requirements be used?

Comment: It has to be ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably ffmpeg is discarding some data because you don't have enough buffer.

I think you need to put these two flags (appliying it to the input) to achieve your goal:

```
-thread_queue_size 512 -rtbufsize 50M
```

I.E.(using the command you typed):

```
    .\ffmpeg.exe -threads auto -y -i input0 -i input1 \
    -thread_queue_size 512 -rtbufsize 50M \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080[v0];[1:v]scale=480x270[v1];[v0][v1]overlay=1440:810[v2]" \
    -map [v2] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy output.mp4
```

It worked for me.